# Расшифровать php файл

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Есть файл под названием functions_messages-enc.php
Как я понял окончание -enc добавлено в качестве метки то что файл сжат.
В данной папке есть также файлы например functions_random.php и functions_random-enc.php.
В файле без окончания -enc информация не сжата и возможно к редактированию. А вот файла functions_messages.php (без -enc) нету. 
В этом файле, функции которые мне необходимо изменить. 
Дайте любую информацию что это может быть. Как это можно исправить. Что угодно.
Ниже предоставлен код данного файла (functions_messages-enc.php)

```
<?php //0046a
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);
?>
HR+cPngg1V3qMFx7bKQGqx4NTynFQRf2j1QXbFXtiTq3KR7YMixK8tSFGox7q21AqOrCLAmX0r09
znOp1/ZEs6SeWOzf373NC0MjzFCEnKHDH7aLKxYI9qaHV03d6iMErkbe5eaQtQRFbkVky22ACEhZ
eySK6Ne6Fpg5ajxLySbemZ4KJyY/eSI37dpnTzEH7YUs3+stD6R07gPQcjJd/ZVq07yGhEUgVPDh
NpwLYfoEppHKqWajQ53qKuKsjF/j8+ia3fPxyc9AEn76ObkQ0g7VQWg81X5m5eJMN//UkZ5fheI6
HPvuurOlgZyGJpKjXcv8QVhSqpGG4kLGzBaxh2uCXum4J4Bfy7tmf9mnsGrPVyOv+O1jUFsfJBvh
SrdkNFb3hGGBFWqe4I3O4IrFquwyR3RJ9pAab+tAwm8ib8hWu2CNOlg6ptlPDHX7Zy8bsA2MB90Y
lPWBoy91mwCOHPvCXVkeH+EhoqhjyNxUUFjFo+Q53ghEdTgYAA9shFeDFZcEN+rADsL3pSkbV0dq
XakT5HeHdbF9pNImjD7aiTM0idblmSfsE7sItZrFhgV4aCj77TEeOUjK2WWS9C/RObxi2rqGRq+Y
uwLTffNd9HOO2S+mhNrmnqFlKMGqBAvIODxHX25z9X8KqLxB/YQlfOMVNbVCMfS/jgU0IE330Xt8
agdMh3JtzKxebBmZlwmLtOMrFaqoOC/n2uL4QGhRWjtecV/MgIuxOwsVm1Ln61eORdGWlOMtB4zR
QbEHLm81ZfOCH1gGrzbebgjLLm2C5+VE2LfqvPA4v9/jkgQIKBQA1HSue6fRlh4/hlRmmDfBbwye
O/DFPDsbrQGPL0Frli3WRqzVmeOuhQKbfvyP/rAHltdT7P+UxLsEE/r3pYXtrANy8a+pN50xNK3Q
2Z5ZcyLbeR+OQNL0JzBHRqEL0tWXTEWakQTm3bwWAOpjWzHf1O2eiJa0YRKC19pgRy6CEqu7zHiQ
8jIPKKp/oaQ+6MTMjnNElGenGSm+QUcqwsmEGDbP68vNkhBTJXHi6j6UW4MQRzZQpWiGO9nGVDUG
eA2RSXBg+ZAIq30M5vP7TpuwC7T4e1xipMHLZu1cf259s/fWgw43u6CsQ2E55gzsc85S599CZqTT
pwd5/bHWWxYUDAx6MD8rvIMiMbNYW7FeLSlU5xQ4FtgovSvcMQD+hnkNpjmaPG5m4uGXN6YpKOmi
5s2u5hlEtJr/dMIJKhNmTqpAckpSZdiqeVXqgHhQXM3jWffEXDxHpSdTzBsYBghezm4BaVfCXjSM
xw1Y2G/VhXnFebNf82V8N8ne4ZvyhqZgQO7x3qIM3jc4LlynkfYOYiVocpaRxbK26bQkK6m9sbrS
rVoMWF6O2puN1RLZHKp4Wi4VaE54cBxk6xoWRTNC2FD3MaxtMzU5Ffsi1MwQnM5WSbuuD3XPzsfD
oIMmssBjbdE44ACLfqbDNO3ozMxpWCB5g/62sgO6wrFqTB6ROYyVmtOw7uTKOdg4lL3GHpW1mdTf
dED1vk92CZB65kqfmxR2EWHHCFHrgOIrXC7g8fL3b0tbMgynvdTF2Xd5rlw3MdlP00CdCO14n/yC
mPHJGGnBTp6jhx14kzEcrjpahh3YvT56B3Aqr0s5raOwWtONdn8WPGjEJpT/qgVDEj5jiTu4DJ+6
n2dQ1g5y//wd/S41QYAJwIw9RqL+ac8u25CgTUJpEmRIWu/QmKo3jU5vnYHt6oSdGFt3TR1ROKCG
3FtznxGdahIQKrHTdgVMs7z6G5WC9JqruBLI4jwOpGh12Fe7GpGl8DEhk93PTYVouAF0J5MTvGzJ
J25+1FA3NlEnDgCvakidPvOLmpK1QTHQ98kF1lN4A2S4+qczXBmR0GUx9QgJspZHntS8BxmNJNKX
vd2tbU1xCHBWsPBgVnFJxxvcDg+24w1aKltpgnPRNHnpLRfnDJX8LgiaD94GXRP4qyHQy36lIQpK
PZgwu4yXB1/mT2hB7cV+RwC6CAX0+TgjavAw2uiF1Oa6ZZZ/wLtrKL/oAIHnepPujcNBgPq+ds7f
h5x4OS+nHfjx0h6NYbNcCR8PtaBJe6vAHttkIAP4oDVrH182XrsIeYOqbCeogSZjEdE6Ux45VfVz
B5IfXJejkpJNOQcgem3fRQxlEiNFHQMrFjSH2fa6kO16OV6jHCsVc5dsyOhK18zwtrVdDVms9oAJ
iGYGj0rtUQQw3orwEG108X+t/uK4DOMfyQRpFNA5AnoKMFxNv4SLIcVsnzHqZkuIzLJzMoN+51rO
6u1gh898auKqq8mTJ09dTjTVpW5dSc/Hu9N+nqsL5DkOWXMfQuccr4lbtRkyNoYGo1Qwb8r4J6+n
bs8mW/Aw1VzJnF7hpP7VYKbmkYnuSozHbLwq2f/Be2NUXBlbmNAsiXfRZXHa5o7otdbnuNVJ0S9b
nU69V0+qbZZ768+gSwOlqv7WaBNZa3r9qNkZkDNqzEb1Ic2gjtBWtJB0LfNzT4Mt1PKmOaBfU06d
trpEZ25FygqwBWdlrO/BpYKCgp/KUl/rrdIaksb28iK1+bxUB9qbB9jLZtfye030BL9M8zdgPVzK
jaycjuiwFGwpXJw+ch18nVYYFMQsHDwdIkTsOyLiLEoVvQiQGJG5QAhuuc7pNy5QLzKzFjIsUC+U
t1pLrc3307XC4L6PsuMYsAKD69y/lnwbLQF3v0D1sXdYen5A/rPiV5aF4ophQOL7PUIBixqE+uv0
XGynZu9YXhOf1PEAXx9ruPi4/XsUfIuCcH0GGjormv+YDdlVSOfeLFtd0tYFqdcLCIjcxAut+kxK
r4iZ3rUCL7KqwJdg7fXJuAIfrunexh7LL9FKl5QPT/Ln6OPvYYPpkNDpO/j8cDp/JzkaLzuB398o
1EYayrvZgK940DV46RUM4U7lgA+jpqKEupF+Lr+cYe4lBQDijfDzPbXZ3/qVsKrU8Ljfbu7kVOuP
G9QrGvzG+A86FhLO2F7OO5LBlJjrrP88tNZfP1Q9TGab5IItnxlki9caY7vbCSrbIlOItsIwslo7
kV+3l8BOb3gPJnEA3evy71vU/WaKGF8P1Ijm0UJqTTkNmiHWwYimDRBMOsqRp25TSzq8acyupfi9
Pqm/cG7b5Hi+ySZi0WzbXS6WXys879ULkDazSlQvJzr44mJ2rKyZRKhpB9pXBdDsU5qStci2N66t
6wZZkhBVFUkSJC2uTZFphdDdsyPz17XTeYzSML3yCvxTajF9LHUuYph8DBgm+ah9clydCkdT3DNS
lHT9g4AJj1mZpR7s4g7kZoSU11wS6dS3NZRxfc6PVZ2FHv3pAoN5fBxViM4ZXr17CWhrPhglY2B/
kmDKxa6HCXkVQBrAZEpfwcX2PJLtB9fTn353NS1GYkGlpi+5wsvlHUJM97FvkmpAVQGLMutLy2PM
/OwodrPaUaNxZqef+FcC/1/eikK1vq0SM2fsO51/xAoJ7JbQeqMhKYvgrQ0miJ9AkMwXIf/alKtf
81DxTmlRxsc/S8Uuhb3AjczUvR5i466xnZ7C4ek8LgnHrSCrZ9OoMSDS9CjdXCi8UqMY7J/bPfGv
5NwpVpO7WRncUjFTQqJ3uW1Mygq8MpkM5udDMGmwIOVbIUlPS9hH5zNOwqo4a2b7Fd1zqcoijLva
/dnpWvXEjY/F3QqKE8FdsmIE7iLmtiVDEcrY3P9gr9RB7eiwqajyaOGT2NX47n3UgysHNZHDGPSY
3uYOMG+GeN1ipxnQItowSFGm2W8KDrxGngQiED/JqX/uCsHu2twqaEe2QkWOK+VM1joZTDaBsMrs
L4c0hYCefAepBqAWOrhEENAsPAAKirOBoiFdT5qubnmfQikMOYz+hkFv7CDN48mNB8CWzn9Gi0XQ
QynjO+oOyZaXN+qVBckqCwg/KX67eKcdc6fRroPCe54Ou19zb0GqrTjbN+6x4Ram+Fk3Om6K0jRU
vM9AYb4rxqW3ZOzoMj4cGStAuiC6GTM56fa/W3sq3g5dwdg1uHvEf8vvXuG0vo4hkcWsZpbVErpu
3TFcHfifZW7kNvSrqGLPBZlZjfYyHf/Gz9NO1pU5+JfygyS5Q6AGFZAJWUANcjG2558D66KcK8DS
205TMHXqJ+DXFTooVjvTKlHc4QWnKdkhnzLYehkPj4omUWl7gaKs/qXYAvWWYGEmY2UNzK+6LOvP
qO0cafZdfWTpIAduNEJPPKPMuNteSDT6g0dKr5WouYYeu7DFuNC0ugpeInKd2OdSb7+8eQHHlmWK
bYv9teW6crtvuc2JWgYcmfsMmRP8wGyNHM9pRFzPt5ruKlfdFw4hWURYYK7/8/+yaihWtqbWWWuX
57uZ97qlf3bFlrR6fGg8oOOIqp/iZ8FyltgYi6OYROADbslZbdMCN7mrXjXXMv3rwbtG6/eGIQNt
YuI+7D0nE9usHl0wNg/O/CoO6bJtwfjAWAk7gwlEoe/Y8fc1XmqvXP9VZY/B9uu0pM6ccELTO0/E
4Ssq16r+6QV1z7eiUpvaDD29iuiI6+3EHWgB2uD8UUAT1h1ED9KC24SoCJP22F94nDlUHtQ3seJp
lL8LRZfzw3xtVY0X34lzonc0QO6tAylm7HdkC/WjirTs091OMtnLyOw6it17MA1iJR5sRE6biIQ8
sh+PZJKmjTMzndE1Hy6EK6niAdkVn9rXwitblikmn1ax4Axdw316GsiA4uZk30S/+B3kMq9abOP5
I9DqC2K/A4Gztq5jofgTXjELg1/rVF86SrXUhepylSRq1aApNJIEhw56GrHgo2bfnuJdhEZxiAWC
Gs//y760YNJCPBWjT7NSUmbDudTkPzx5Xe8HmrWl2Hag8DmDwcEW/ZV3OjeJS1Glo4CarBzV+39l
Av+UWG6n6x3j2GgGDkp2hbUF1OiLvcyeCGkAefVC0IE/MJ9ril+9PsWbdMwpC96ZKFGTpTFMIflt
tvRZJ6nJfpG7lmj0hsvYHQNmINo9/eW/Dt9JvKXDkG14nX/E4w3PeY7nAD4LwoEgPiZvPxl6Ppk8
upDPz7yxkph0VKVF8ZTpdA2XTPG8WB1diVlH5Zk+dFTordZveTrvsAle3qukbDnSnbSEj19888qn
wA/ujqEimpZ4AZCQANUuiRPqpstbAEJ4x9UNWJiO5XJ1c1mPCrtnl3NmOqobiRj4iq+T7Mb33a3u
FS+Qft9+YNgRA3M24bm0J5QSpZjrldWALwrEbYULelMEaXUyNPbzGWKbtKQxx2eeGtT9JqlZwvLZ
v9zD+pgJZlPvIJbuSS2dcAsvrBhC9rYWJ2bo2P1ikFxYHEBlGpSFAPsl94hZziCFwmF4LVMuxWIh
0qpErdk/0TOqJsrHGS7w6YfAPzCDdoX+EDkPvnbNsPQEOFult6G3JwC+lzBXCUk2K6IEbFy4Pl2u
kgXDlEpmVB7xzcv5MqPzc/dhiJ1yb5lYwT2XfpQARthlC3OMUUjTnXOHvCBO4MAOYMzW19hNVw7U
S91ZcImq78GF/iGA/ve7rGsC6VGDDv/mg9C+v+bISZ5VVgLP+Jytd4QCrGBOSqpIza//DjCJHaAn
/GdlQQc4Nmu0T+4ZFsP7c5HGUZakvaCqKdpWyvAQ4fOhzY1i7OEopxzEyuScBzJCm3RAbaKI/ezO
M8tnGwPiuzBTR56MyCrsKFvLeB1dZ+sUr01VcPXO1b3UJu1cN4t0aBeGFW2C5DDW0llaijQIrfDs
/v9kgO3xXBgkN+mJPQ/yayGDxrG/TdNnJS05M0xYB7xcpBAKi0nSS+TYqon0MRcvjPRLJYrcdvnG
MTCnWg/fZI2eDcanYrcd2KCrCJV87vp1mSACzyEoWqW/wnuW1sxmlGcHMWftoJ3mjZS35pJLXVNE
09cyKmMtPav3jaBeG7FHkwfX0aE+GW3CM9oE7cCKoYDWaHpFhfD3CeFkMTvMNBrk5wI1ZclfY4+5
VxBTDYUhAMjBGiTfEyLq5sJOy6UWVhfXuOTXXkIEyCFOwCkwuFKMeiV/iBteFL54cTes0NbcFykb
D9fKNOCto67dJx3s5rB9jTOUAKC7UkR7DGazIiJngfqKNVaHjFQw9oNEox3THr03CiNecN29zczY
8/XVBs/DzslYJkDKRnjTCuDAdQJyt3Phh5eac5aBX/BjuJcnbhwGHqH6N9na9SCmzcEbE23BkRpr
dP04OWXzxoK0XQU3s5nhSOBPMHRhD42pcbCQCoNKU45xGp9XNUExAGkeFVzGnSF5or7PuK7dc4qU
4HgkeIQuJZBVl16i+oBpnK+FdaSelBQFGPFDm+xh5vLPODeVGfS/+QKtypx2RmHZ7SyUWeYoNpwZ
+LfPjcLmUQNtaC6gbSg7TedDXs2bbcLtb+GfTf243yi//fDH6+aLuwNVm/16jvjK+elDC5jtsmL7
ViAu7Pz5woZipvO39a5dRrqWjWSlxl6Y/rlnXhGAFxGAW0S6AEj5BfijzdIgqpkQJOlC228b2aMy
MQBOlLbKRrAT/wOTGo58KrJypt8tELpDPioCWt2p7ZVUzswfHLANcOpHZJToWqU9sbllg5wyvTDL
vJZ4qJ/5rDDWGbMgUMe7/xDKvzG9tsDLKF5pjxOzb78L8FJuRHMRh+o5crzXZr8ZHAGAu0w5LCBR
qmj8q5Qd7iuIjX3gVrHgH73oxVcgMgiACzwKAz5ChRmfweGQBxyU53LtLsiVePY9sQesw/8aZ341
cg4E3AyPKBN/0LgZGaOoIc2VI03LFmyUlJLx7Gast0YJ6YOL9zasxlTBOyrnQSocudNAPAhFM0o1
RzhLYiLfD5+6WSPvSM3z0c9EWfwE6U5AnMBhC4rJl2b1emFnPJDpkXH0jD4c/B6sxBkq2Z6awKtW
zSSh0U3p1Fov5Ct7YQGV+WWaA49i9AqASH3m7Hg30+yjObPOhUwWOI6a2IYdrqAFhe29BrL1ttYY
lyPlCpGd0dCOCLJzd/x8al8MB3ZVtbzUTHwpcKv4b5h8/NqthErRvhSnin5JxBbEysZ3TcPmcIC1
ASRX5GC2yrtcnfPSXNUqJUtS5/6mvxVJSWWWa6cx7rdItkAXA/ij4VEUibQGdGOQN66nHYSXYL+Y
qIrKi5HdvIgM9wldBsA3MCqnJz0Q3F2CCX+drVYJCZJQOayWftskcQY8xq1NorcV75ZZsnefXLht
Nfa6cr12YvWoAHu+fK6X3vAGsyJMTckriZRK0q4kJI6ibigZkWdu9o/kd/ge9q6Rb9GzUNHIbHYQ
UrwCQoj6QBEoCsYOHIh6u3CfLmdDvwg1xl2Op6gN1XNrTqSP2qSbouPJGQR5jEAe6hD4NXvYinz1
YIYVUUKfu8b1JY1iN8lSYt+DP9iJdonnJHjy+rrP8X53dFIU4Lv3m+KoM5XpJUnqIP9oPSuqyFS+
dvj91ewKYiQDnqQU5Vs6d2V/5w5Ecf1d3gC9eAG58xFb1iIQJTExe2ITAQ60w9bQ0qK9EdOsoeCb
9i09Lu0lhz34xUuCG0Skg2qQVaQyBI6i6EJYWijyhCDLfZPJ/Xf8KlPQGN2d/OwDtT/xZ2lFgXMF
GAHxeXMvapXWg+hhpENqrB7bJVFkWM7HIFJYbIboTZhi2dWnaw9e0AaYDIOCgqrpDR4s/s7/1BKA
XcIEffuB0NTCTweLIXs1qWTfpY5HTeb0npDK5icY7hs+/lKc+KMsu0uWfzReHSK8B9I593qTinKl
XcDvAzAF1kHaOW6f/7MtxY+3/w8M06z3/Cvg3rPTMrp/OFTLVaRqcVcWWFoAfcK3ZNuBTPTOZLzs
kKtldaWBLCX6OKl8DroJH0eh1XUuqkPecHRVsibJpx4IptrYJNWLxG5aOjiZ89JYdxGOhmxK9x9A
Cn0ccz7DcqZMV3tmes5c342DK///A9VdMHNQb/91B1pIY4hee4pTdCSGLFCOrLDouSpiaEcw4uAD
s1xDrv6mAPu9XERFbFCC5LU+VqTTl7VtQyRVT2IqgyxUHkSDQnpruATqowc17i8lBCaku8IBNNUR
JpTnxtjtFcZ9BxFfWrcxRceIP+9iHGnJVBrhZ6qAuH1S69kHmacWxBvJkHKr5S/j9ITf4tEaSkFj
Ysqe3lp8t4Xy0Rhx36cfsp/Xmv6o7jMwqKIxN9laE2cBbo5lLMISkU31SzKp5NlNZB8/VbMywBQk
uEG5avVqUTThgB1tEbEZQFpSymW/PWqK0hkbSmTvJ+ByaBVyD5aF5Nm8wlca/aWzfzFEr08jgfKO
saJ+Gty4WEcE2AZz75M44bWHRywKkp2j0iAC/cgY7aGlC9kTRrcrdO2pDvTJImTwEcvqOyMqN5m0
udx/9gJpmbJWGt4CqRREahOWh5cBe655Bm1+LgqXknH0uExjQys/lJEkZYFGHu2jsHk71+dQXgOa
nrmB+/XvvXu9JfMS9CLyQgJE0rLEmedGoGvUcdbSO0dQ3PorKA4V1J+ui84xAZfGI5RSd0IKRx4U
gNDZHVk6tkmwsjJLMcrnez+W1Q/sPiRTR+S5PSwl+i64xkaaSTekEX+WT3rjAP9GrtB9cewuuBEE
5kfeeiU/4S8TZQPsZcbVN0YShHRdOYSmBR9k0xKR3+893Phxm6bS5efi9ckBUrSjkMQZqBxMa2ls
r7ue3P/3zx1pGN3twBvyjA1sBBadmYVcAWmc8f0dEF/ng6GL10uV5qEnfQkkjj+0AvSoejrBxmpm
BEl481PGQ8xqxG0TdsLzfOzLtDUn+RBNlMKH8q4BGnTLzdDD2iXrw6+WC8enBzFSPKtMuLeW2vvX
9xdWdhWqmaFL4du3XxvO17+kUs0bMLMUIZko2fcdt70jVvlcxGJDAxpF6MrT2KW2RTU3Oba8UqZe
3kfGG6/xrVt51d7RF/de9yv6Cv8/vpIjQERcMvuEeCudCiU2UTKQw5POIMqj9gRNY9xpojByDEfC
66HVmLfblWSBZn+Tk65Jf2k47blldbVc97b0hE8c55sfWFn0fFFMMmhjsxpEz5yWRu89Tj0GCCO5
ZIbU/zniJytliRhrMGG0IYCOJp4jHf1GOApQhGZBJf9dYmlN9S/BbC9nLxCOI4Zg/V3bPOjQSlFh
8oPsBAwtgE1otCR3PCJleaBJ+jSsrd0RJ47UM0BlrlJyHLLtHH6nU6xR5QW/93sbjgcbrvIpQibL
nBtZT8E8keQt9tU0D5MHVPoj6Ep1g3AulYQSPsGDC17ZUPSIxjjk5FVa/+DeKLkGwvk/zQkk5rYS
k7T10eq1AsEK2PSswJ7tjPHuhUtx/lj+2Pu382uOz5g2ootYdpgZikvXzEzq6CHWaimfVZLsR8xL
RKGo1h2mMwgxo5+CaHZCgVUZQIFQxhQqRdsJ7IPRQ2qsexcUzfOa+2hOacDthtfV0PqBqS4ZeV7z
ku93DQkNipBqxiYi5WJ5QG0IJejWkLTZ8yerGT/1ZOb/7qdGw9enrr41pQGm0jWXHf3VcAvAewQ1
gBBOFnq4EGwVPnoeAJx9uhnMnfDczDHeaArENjULPL6r/O9610F5dUgiKcdxRblCmndPKhU3Gg6C
cN3fciYT34nDLbKfqPXLO/3jHP+osAXun7i2/+URlJ2Fbde1hbzNMB45TK+9xb0GXg/5zDxQ67t3
xWCDRjcvSJuSxPMET49gtDpoyAW65QfsBvrfJg5BUUILrJFCkyf/qFrqqHPXTF6+d6SzfK8qujnB
+Fxg3ggDqAkDSV/Umn0LRXhpFyOiq6ejuQItCGzhTPeMfVeEpFxmp7ujD/PjRsJWFGd+T64/oqxN
GU6WZ+XXqqQl17kpkq0Vma6wsGAt1yQKOMZbpNVou8vpwPERYgwpcFty4xlp+wv3P5jgdBdSPvpm
woYGe/G938jTdv8s4W0UG7iUCxKji1RuSMHbAUAi8u7W3T5D6146KoP1AFMQZ13kdgzWPZMxwB4Q
CioU740A8lAtEGCSWUKknURfo5EILTNUDhjNhbcpnRt41zyz/lv9WVXvocU903jfJJe6U6XwgSOH
lXFmUZbItKePg7ze1JgEsWEBsboZf1dvYrBIwLbadgW7h64CruOCWza+jgYSaBkXMuf3zexvMx0V
P8UXr2gdjx9GpidC3rgwAcun22LyPETPsxXW4cd+yM+yhidlxeTEzHk955LCdeFKlb7H9wMkptAR
ZnxWBF4u/DS6SDm6Jsj29pg1uZXxHqzShrgu/X+c2DTcIub8w0civ5y1Ta8PL+xVm/TWCJR+tOX4
Z3vnPuvupzzClim2ddFeENcNjp/Z74b9vnhP34NVucrTGmLEzKmavTWeqMQBtMAnrDi+C/3/FrMG
ZHEKMph4Eg7UU2jIXCx906HmebjC76sR8J2F7EWed76ltyY0t8XCorWJzjKFiXT4qGIHU5yJ7YCv
ZpIxU4mmywkvFrg3KQIUZZcX/UfwTeN6LiWPTuCQF/CF7FbO77mDS35W1unxWu6K9nBGGcxZ+j1p
cMD/347thKI8fFkaqFhtO2izxiZK7KF1sSWBPkPv/4xa8BbgJgnH7dush5saYt1FD0dMk8BJ4ATc
D1aIhALJx4m0VXceAa7E5B5hp/voNfrMMWOt8wpGFYksX6lRGvjFFTYhIebiwQTQUXaE33jXaWC3
fUw8f0dAGLwPnanTNaOkA+pw2iXBndMFz5IGExOk2qsc2tqgrL6pm2L/H1Uwe6BWiDW9++ZpQsaP
iFMH434PEplcwqp9j7zX2rMuQXeqR/+Dl4JCWbdhqoa14DYfY6Lgqio3vS3I4fxsDnIC9AteNtxT
cH8aGVAr8kXtaU0KxfS74LenwIzgrQiL1bvOAXwTkVPwhoD3kqiX4nP0lGAXLIaVERCsoVRKE05l
3QdyrEnKJqWwDCPXIjc6DipnlCJ2ADIvp3vsr2RYsM1wiav16FgstX4E0KkzGNWlxuoHgK9s9jeR
IKr31XBNyN6bqnzz4q22fJMYwDBVJ3SqSyuvA3uCJptmKl1xGRcFRu234pSdgF4nyLLxlbYxCDmQ
JohO3X1RQjurNxfR0vIiwhPcEq6QXDsv9bNfzg08FatvOGcvsuoxOTCHCNH5GPWkDeKAeNXzGx1G
zeApJnZjzezgJISHXyOHkNVj1ytTZXQpACIvD/kr9ASxHXNhR8kpdyZrA+pQBbENL4E5kDuYEH/d
Z9eiRZIQmkQhbUNFmxBUi2NUJYwz8p24MVzsb4ixV1ZagUAOB9qYNWVFnQFPdErs7B3E1qy9ndPW
uQwD4aALKOn6dFT9IBw5h81rXqcRVjUalWxvKRwqk/ONnkh5jF9sXvlvpgyGsJ/jCKM17YfMrAM5
LSUJfIQY2clNbVuqSWlcrUJ4Cfyvxf211g4EYMlI9Q2s7VjqAGlxq7gR8dcXWJrnGIMqwLhCA7Aa
wygRklHprPDFOKagwH93hi5Gbkxxps+8u3YYyihOnF+8itICf38DPRtozvLg41CLHbgBkw74De2q
+7utr1JoPeoTRlztQawcKSLJ4p2UdGH8TIyl8Sp7rauZgbnpTfTSSXosnPFldD9xkADmWJArVLNt
DLccHpwHCrLT5lVcDIY4lLRsVuq2wLL28f9ltrGW/4r0zeIAvk5QnrlqhZRpiIc85qbAU4vY4WYA
l3LdycZqr/ufkPfIVAMC0MCaRW9wEYdX6GlnWAtStQH+JkbpNgOfsfmRDlIH5kd29RNbyb0H05g6
I1pZnpI7+76KVcqDhU05pu3nJ0HnkRy5D38QuO8ddMU2GDc7BfTPSei7poVCRaOzGiePCDgnTIxV
lPSwbotuyu0Bgl6SH40aYGhpbRuDIDJAKdDEMTYUhfCVDxrzn49SUQX3O+HDBFu5GN2YZICa/12y
tm1qr8sGRMEIZj6lD+efGVT8DtQTq5sJn5piLUJzH/cQHT5evEnBjfgBergzG+iVYh7KHBG5pBJA
9gxUQdgfiPzhJm7HD7jES0S4LsAtq+3dAzOaadZC+0kAtaWMvG0zGu5ricPNcqkSzJw5HNcwzcfL
jAQ21eV3NXxD8SwvyY4EcyZTmNr/Gj52BbhfaymNuL5W9fObxoCSvxd/S9QocDAVXNll+H2TB382
Js/CaDliVUnnxE2jCuROd/RIhYxuY23aaB8IHyXLvBN+/phkzgYV2Wv4bpBut17711GN9DWbGMxq
5QrBIjKqwGM2jH0dzZt/5eljKry2RwxlSX4V5XS3exp4LOeVcpz9GZB7XY8HYpwuXyjGTngO2MDs
9oKb9xN2wKtPlZe9S9R+142i6YPVODDsj2qSwNXTmWzG0roQbr62zfOAbh1H+0Baa1xE4kpFm0+6
nSkR3osCUWN+Duf8ZMTtnXdTcYO0ZECGMQAe4xhHGolD/CVp/oQRO9zmobqcgLsgwrcQrFb+5Tcp
GBQ0zPVuvIktfMVWdhW0mszr22pvn1v68s4S7FH4pIFbfdvahO3g5NdcZ04wqWDVYeKXxtNvGWCs
SYRN6UD63GSU3T+02pNu/1sDlvG6fUFhxH/Kf+bSZDVITDjQA/CZHd6F8QYOHfs6lRemEG9OKanq
q0SJ6SCn2lIZPflw0o3z2NWYY0K2XBmsfrspJgmRCTCZl+6TKZRTX8lb4Qz5QdnmMTIvpG3rozCr
yELh69ATJMvMWJ6l6+mqXCevt51iOFIeY/wdS2BlqybqLTSjPFfdFNDkRS8WPQc/pmFbFsSn9rcC
EGyM7BhJezaWY73mgZOFFVmmdZzF01gCqeZ1flpprqLLkoGsrWiJdVI1tKDMhKKXz1QPy2fFjk9L
Btrv4yQGda6+/EtbZAFomr688pGDTMCVylYzcGTf5PmTkS7icjC+A+b+MvQ0aO5ABL+wKDSt6kXL
O1b0axO1wTaDzfA7p98Zp1uwh4oldwvQ5wBZQw7ifBKwRMRLuMDaaPEMYl4OXnXEUuIbttGCxyuZ
QKZt393ap+bsUjuvduAjt/jriF9/37qgS08tqdulYUASTbVjLjCfcGymzKqwwUHL+cNkDe3sI/e1
6EmGORI0rEWGZPVcP6etAIfZgkhKiMzPDohr9sNPneHchdm3y8x+ik2HJP6EHJuxMT4CXiPhWDnR
+aIj7dMDZbRI90FnHzOmmjlH+6EQ2GXIJtweFYYmGswefc8ZjT3ea1SCqqd6KHsbwVqYBKPM3mcm
uapgcMaL0Iu8wGhGzWiw3iVvsciR9YbaWevX2sV5B6EMZMJQvht16ZyfDQJa9/5afa5c/VLe4MUw
8kHVdRbeMEkZERgkHFAMv0z23xfw2FMU/VdB+YmLYoLnyWvItIMhXKk2tWwYjIMT21Vi5M131y1I
fMdbIhxZAHV4gxqXt8rOKuSvw8vCrA4DInk2lcBvETN7c9j9HBS3WGKdHff/m4W2VZ3CUW5zMy4k
igFRoYBfM2zJZTYGZU3rtE+QHTalhKtkm1ThRu2Q49+2bJO9MlbSyDxAGsNZdM8PNhR98HT8E2I7
srbHj3tQx6Yt0PRztrWUy7be62H/8LSzaPZ2A0SdaM/PBFgqkXVWLxyGz7iMAKGPpVZ3LogIWSmA
8a/1qQwowTxakjro9BLW9/1lrqFsFTNKpcBd4/z5FeOlcpBp3dv+Yz/vQyMY66KjKkVQLSTXg5rN
526ozumLinwzfP4CYIIPpVWABuWsllmFTXJMqfGkIccBJhYjgWSVOVmiv9O3KmUejO/4fScEensI
xdV1JUkA7gZFr9F12iHXA3THgJAuBZQNaRPovTqtFNnBjdlkC38J/jcqDhMUm6vnu8NlmErxoKOm
ILkoExyucfY8n8QdgI+GqduW8wBy+JVMiK2+Yp/B7XheJLc+3048GMX1z19EDoU5bL17tLpE0+/H
RKzZD10fWVrEnRZhnNep5yoebOidCAo6QY/dzjwxKmobFzguCs3B7tP7myIR+fz2YDxGiVX6E/iO
f8kmMua090Spa7oJGH9nawz4xFOmnEUADrln/Wtc4L0a0HJXfiEAYllfGTQ93gynhr8WaPgMXObr
OCdA7Ji8TYUoAWJBmkwapmfyOh/kxNaFVeSgc1hVFnAHQ1ku7CZhlX0gkUrRMZj4F+PFZ2pVWhs2
vU/hbny6PqRo3ieDCAXOQ2XjySrBW7CGzCQqwHJCpZgHrWFbV2TW9SicvLcAW4Xs7P75c71iMfqP
pTSbnvLjZea8zlWM/Ty4BIKCbLM+sWodUEPoIF2TRRUpp1ZbStDiH0R8oTwsyg31Rj+LEhIr1qOE
8W7OY77InTKvbQK8ox1HF+0s26EjMl0mbWesHqpkIId/xKBahih1HJ+gylL2/9mXnxoIuRLtu35M
EnaJOdnxObhIzIOujZwzhfYEEt1+8uA1hIcIJRfS2V8GmmEAJsBKWyaaO5bYaINnEY3JyfdnQXNY
3MAOzYiBOjBMWAWfyeEdBB4nu0Skc2QvTPmwdQIJhXBLvf+GsU7hCD0mjxhqcDZQ/1bRr3kSyGGY
WSNf0BZzwSYKZGWD7iELMz7OEsXkVdZ6wDQurq5W5KWbovKiOonYuSPhfJwBx7LOmajHkkIRbec6
BNrSS4gUN0xZlTQnkHHAH5uCqokePOsl629+ZG5zIl76awHL/bueCBR/o8+vCFIEY9w4OgS+ccHO
BK1xHVy2q1ixAEqcRA6Hn0KMifOxBxUuraCs7nsiwcMjaJK/2vN9Q4ts9Q0HBUopTXXxWYp10yCT
5dcKvOmZuUL/WFm3XILRdGDCwSI40xQu2vTiCYy1ZCmYBS6iwWn2c6ffW/qzONLym4KR7U6wo/Cs
742BHR4d2k71joKoIH6O5MFhnKdVzHhV1qeUIVoPdw2FUIXAdzJLHZ5DnfHsV/Xo2bOPFadWfVjO
/xEm0XaOe1pKbc3Tgu7D6xfnnq2l20VJsYxHh8Dyz1SrG32V0HvZ6zxm/gWny+vUfBuAD7UCVKqS
lahq9XhGCHwwJvOh5FmafPJjGAo8RyXlH6+seio/SM0iBssUeKou5bwRqodO7cvPa82kMyTu+rqt
oOT66+Gvlke8sEMmnGUrOCSVJqdhIInqlUfCc//b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Походу так:

```html
<?php

function deleteMessage($id) {
 global $db;

 $sql =  . 'DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE id=' . $id;
 $db->query( $sql );
 return 0 < $db->affected_rows(  );
}

function getMessageEarmark($id) {
 global $db;

 $res = '';
 $sql =  . '
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM M.`dt_created`) AS `year_month`
  FROM `messages` M
  WHERE id=' . $id . '
 ';
 $db->query( $sql );

 if ($db->next_record(  )) {
  $db->f( 'year_month' );
  $res = ;
 }

 return $res;
}

function getMessagesEarmarks($pars) {
 global $db;

 intval( $pars['user_id'] );
 $user_id = ;
 $pars['messagebox'];
 user_level(  );
 $my_level = $messagebox = ;
 isAdmin( $my_level );
 $admin = $list = array(  );
 $where = 'WHERE 1';
 switch ($messagebox) {
 case 'inbox': {
   $where .= (!$admin ?  . ' AND ( M.to_id=' . $user_id . ' )' : '');
   $where .= ' AND (M.`status`>=0) AND (M.`deleted_inbox`=0)';
   break;
  }

 case 'outbox': {
   $where .= (!$admin ?  . ' AND ( M.from_id=' . $user_id . ' )' : '');
   $where .= ' AND (M.`status`>=0) AND (M.`deleted_sent`=0)';
   break;
  }

 case 'draft': {
   $where .= (!$admin ?  . ' AND ( M.from_id=' . $user_id . ' )' : '');
   $where .= ' AND (M.`status`=-1)';
   break;
  }
 }

 break;
 $project_id = (isset( $_REQUEST['project_id'] ) ? intval( $_REQUEST['project_id'] ) : 0);
 $where_project = (0 <= $project_id ? (  . ' AND (M.project_id=' . $project_id . ')' ) : '');
 $sql =  . '
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM M.`dt_created`) AS `year_month`,
      YEAR(M.`dt_created`) AS `year`,
      MONTHNAME(M.`dt_created`) AS `month_name`,
      COUNT(M.`id`) AS `count`
  FROM `messages` M
  ' . $where . '
  ' . $where_project . '
    GROUP BY `year_month`
    ORDER BY `year_month` DESC
 ';
 $db->query( $sql );
 $i = 290;

 while ($db->next_record(  )) {
  $list[$i++] = array( 'year_month' => $db->f( 'year_month' ), 'year' => $db->f( 'year' ), 'month_name' => $db->f( 'month_name' ), 'count' => $db->f( 'count' ) );
 }

 return $list;
}

function getAllMessageFolders($user_id = 0) {
 global $db;

 $i = 205;
 $folders = array(  );
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `message_folder`' . (  . ' WHERE (user_id=0) OR (user_id=' . $user_id . ') ORDER BY name' );
 $db->query( $sql );

 while ($db->next_record(  )) {
  $folders[$i++] = array( 'id' => $db->f( 'id' ), 'name' => $db->f( 'name' ) );
 }

 return $folders;
}

function getMessageFolderId($user_id, $name) {
 global $db;

 strtoupper( $name );
 $name = ;
 $sql = (  . 'SELECT id FROM `message_folder` WHERE UPPER(name)=\'' . $name . '\'' );
 $db->query( $sql );
 $db->next_record(  );
 return $db->f( 'id' );
}

function addMessageFolder($user_id, $name) {
 global $db;

 $query =  . 'INSERT INTO `message_folder` (user_id,name) VALUES (' . $user_id . ', \'' . $name . '\')';
 $db->query( $query );
 return $db->last_insert_id(  );
}

function getMessageFolderName($id) {
 global $db;

 $sql =  . 'SELECT name FROM `message_folder` WHERE id=' . $id;
 $db->query( $sql );
 $db->next_record(  );
 return $db->f( 'name' );
}

function deleteMessageFolder($id) {
 global $db;

 $sql =  . 'DELETE FROM `message_folder` WHERE id=' . $id;
 $db->query( $sql );

 if (0 < $db->affected_rows(  )) {
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}

function getMessageList($pars = array(  )) {
 global $db;

 $user_id = (isset( $pars['user_id'] ) ? $pars['user_id'] : 0);
 $msg_id = (isset( $pars['msg_id'] ) ? $pars['msg_id'] : 0);
 $_SESSION['messages.messagebox'];
 $messagebox = ;
 $project_id = (isset( $pars['project_id'] ) ? $pars['project_id'] : 0);
 $folder_id = (isset( $pars['folder_id'] ) ? $pars['folder_id'] : 0);
 $sort_column = (isset( $pars['sort_column'] ) ? $pars['sort_column'] : 'from_username');
 $sort_order = (isset( $pars['sort_order'] ) ? $pars['sort_order'] : 'ASC');
 $earmark_id = (isset( $pars['earmark_id'] ) ? $pars['earmark_id'] : '');
 $i = 480;
 switch ($messagebox) {
 case 'inbox': {
   $where = '(M.status>=0) AND ( NOT `deleted_inbox`)';

   if (!isAdmin( user_level(  ) )) {
    $where .= (  . ' AND (M.to_id=' . $user_id . ')' );
   }

   break;
  }

 case 'outbox': {
   $where = '(M.status>=0) AND ( NOT `deleted_sent`)';

   if (!isAdmin( user_level(  ) )) {
    $where .= (  . ' AND (M.from_id=' . $user_id . ')' );
   }

   break;
  }

 case 'draft': {
   $where = '(M.`status`=-1)';

   if (!isAdmin( user_level(  ) )) {
    $where .= (  . ' AND (M.from_id=' . $user_id . ')' );
   }

   break;
  }
 }


 if ($user_id == 1) {
  $where =  . '(M.from_id=' . $user_id . ') OR (M.from_id=0)';
 }
 else {
  $where = (  . '(M.from_id=' . $user_id . ')' );
 }

 break;

 if (0 < $folder_id) {
  $folder = (  . ' AND (folder_id=' . $folder_id . ')' );
 }
 else {
  $folder = '';
 }


 if (0 < $project_id) {
  $where_project = (  . ' AND (project_id=' . $project_id . ')' );
 }
 else {
  $where_project = '';
 }

 $sort_column = (issets( $sort_column ) ? $sort_column : 'from_username');
 $where_msg_id = '';

 if (!empty( $$earmark_id )) {
  intval( substr( $earmark_id, 0, 4 ) );
  $year = ;
  intval( substr( $earmark_id, -2 ) );
  $month = ;
  $where_date =  . ' AND ( YEAR(M.dt_created)=\'' . $year . '\' AND MONTH(M.dt_created)=\'' . $month . '\' )';
 }
 else {
  $where_date = '';
 }

 $messages = array(  );
 $sql = 'SELECT M.*, \'\' AS metatag' . ',P.name AS project_name' . ',F.name AS folder_name' . ',CONCAT(AB.firstname,\' \',AB.lastname) AS to_fullname' . ',( SELECT CONCAT(A.firstname,\' \',A.lastname) FROM `address_book` A WHERE (M.from_id=A.user_id) ) AS from_fullname' . ',( SELECT U.username FROM `users` U WHERE (M.from_id=U.id) ) AS from_username' . ',( SELECT U.email FROM `users` U WHERE (M.from_id=U.id) ) AS from_email' . ',( SELECT U.username FROM `users` U WHERE (M.to_id=U.id) ) AS to_username' . ',( SELECT U.email FROM `users` U WHERE (M.to_id=U.id) ) AS to_email' . ' FROM `messages` M' . ' LEFT JOIN `message_folder` F ON (F.id=M.folder_id)' . ' LEFT JOIN `projects_projects` P ON (P.id=M.project_id)' . ' LEFT JOIN `address_book` AB ON (AB.user_id=M.to_id)' . (  . ' WHERE ' . $where ) . $folder . $where_project . $where_date . $where_msg_id . (  . ' ORDER by `id` DESC, `' . $sort_column . '` ' . $sort_order ) . ' LIMIT 200';
 $db->query( $sql );

 while ($db->next_record(  )) {
  $db->f( 'to_email' );
  $to = ;
  $db->f( 'color_id' );
  $color_id = ;

  if ($color_id == '0') {
   $color_id = '#FFFFFF';
  }

  $color_id = (issets( $color_id ) ? $color_id : '#FFFFFF');
  $messages[$i++] = array( 'id' => $db->f( 'id' ), 'from_text' => $db->f( 'from_email' ), 'to_id' => $db->f( 'to_id' ), 'to_text' => $to, 'to_fullname' => $db->f( 'to_fullname' ), 'to_username' => $db->f( 'to_username' ), 'from_id' => $db->f( 'from_id' ), 'from_fullname' => $db->f( 'from_fullname' ), 'from_username' => $db->f( 'from_username' ), 'subject' => stringFromSQL( $db->f( 'subject' ) ), 'message' => stringFromSQL( $db->f( 'message' ) ), 'status' => $db->f( 'status' ), 'dt_created' => $db->f( 'dt_created' ), 'project_id' => $db->f( 'project_id' ), 'project_name' => $db->f( 'project_name' ), 'color_id' => $color_id, 'folder_id' => $db->f( 'folder_id' ), 'folder_name' => $db->f( 'folder_name' ), 'metatag' => $db->f( 'metatag' ), 'size' => $db->f( 'size' ), 'debug' => $sql );
 }

 return $messages;
}

function exportMessagesToXml($user_id, $export_file) {
 new XmlWriter(  );
 $xml = ;
 $xml->openURI( $export_file );
 $xml->startDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
 WriteMessagesToXml( $user_id, $xml );
 $xml->endDocument(  );
 $xml->flush(  );
}

function WriteMessagesToXml($user_id, $xml) {
 getAllMessagesSimple( $user_id );
 $messages = ;
 $xml->startElement( 'Messages' );
 foreach ($messages as ) {
  $val = ;
  $key = ;
  $xml->startElement( 'Message' );
  foreach ($val as ) {
   $msg_val = ;
   $msg_key = ;
   $xml->writeElement( $msg_key, $msg_val );
  }

  $xml->endElement(  );
 }

 $xml->endElement(  );
}

function parseMsg($mvalues) {
 $i = 199;

 while ($i < count( $mvalues )) {
  if (isset( $mvalues[$i]['value'] )) {
   $mol[$mvalues[$i]['tag']] = $mvalues[$i]['value'];
  }
  else {
   $mol[$mvalues[$i]['tag']] = '';
  }

  ++$i;
 }

 return $mol;
}

function readDatabase($filename) {
 implode( '', file( $filename ) );
 $data = ;
 xml_parser_create(  );
 $parser = ;
 xml_parser_set_option( $parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0 );
 xml_parser_set_option( $parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1 );
 xml_parse_into_struct( $parser, $data, $values, $tags );
 xml_parser_free( $parser );
 foreach ($tags as ) {
  $val = ;
  $key = ;

  if ($key == 'Message') {
   $molranges = $filename;
   $i = 244;

   while ($i < count( $molranges )) {
    $offset = $molranges[$i] + 1;
    $len = $molranges[$i + 1] - $offset;
    $tdb[] = parseMsg( array_slice( $values, $offset, $len ) );
    $i += 246;
   }

   continue;
  }

  jmp;
  continue;
 }

 return $tdb;
}

function exportTableToCSV($table, $export_file, $where = '') {
 global $db;

 $sql = (  . 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \'' . $export_file . '\'' ) . ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ' . ' LINES TERMINATED BY \'
\'' . (  . ' FROM `' . $table . '` ' . $where . ';' );
 $db->query( $sql );
}

function importTableFromCSV($table, $export_file) {
 global $db;

 $sql = (  . 'LOAD DATA INFILE \'' . $export_file . '\' REPLACE INTO TABLE `' . $table . '`' ) . ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ' . ' LINES TERMINATED BY \'
\'';
 $db->query( $sql );
}

?>
```

Comment: Желательно объяснять, как вы это сделали, чтобы в дальнейшем человек опять не пришел с той-же проблемой, только уже с другим файлом. Внесите в вопрос правки для более детального объяснения.

Answer (score 6):

Файл не "сжат". 
Сжимать РНР файлы не имеет смысла.

Файл закодирован. Для того, чтобы **никто не мог изменить находящиеся в нем функции.**

Если хочется менять функции, то надо либо пользоваться платными скриптами с открытым кодом, либо - предпочтительнее - бесплатными, коих для любых задач написаны сотни и тысячи.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью за с ответом товарища Ипатьев'а.
Файл закодирован, возможно использовался Zend encoder (пакет Zend Guard), первым делом необходимо выяснить, что это за кодировочка такая )
Если вы любите такие головоломки дерзайте, а так лучше воспользоваться бесплатными аналогами.

Comment: Мне кажется, или там действительно написано "IonCube" и можно не гадать чем именно оно накрыто?

Comment: не заметил )
сарказм заценил )